# Getting dependencies error while installing R packages in Ubuntu Using pacman

Tags: r, pacman-package-manager

I am using `pacman` to install and load the mentioned libraries. But it is throwing a dependency error and lock error in installing `caret`.
My main motive to use this library was to auto detect the libraries in R so that if present, load the library else install and load.

`pacman::p_load(dplyr,caret,plyr)` was the code that I used.

Comment: it says you are missing a dependency and it fails?

Comment: Can you show the output with the dependency error?

Comment: @rawr yes it fails

Comment: @iago ERROR: failed to lock directory ‘/home/ubuntu/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6’ for modifying
Try removing ‘/home/ubuntu/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/00LOCK-Rcpp’
ERROR: dependency ‘Rcpp’ is not available for package ‘prodlim’
* removing ‘/home/ubuntu/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/prodlim’
ERROR: dependency ‘Rcpp’ is not available for package ‘scales’
* removing ‘/home/ubuntu/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/scales’

Comment: Do you have installed  package `Rcpp`? If (when) this is the case, can you try your code again after restarting R session? If yet does not work and the version of `Rcpp` you have installed is not the last one, can you upload it before trying again?

Answer (score 1):

```
install.packages("Rcpp", dependencies = TRUE, INSTALL_opts = '--no-lock')
```

In place of Rcpp you can pass a variable which will change according to your iterations for every record on the list having the names of libraries to be downloaded.
It solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

The dependency error may be due to `pacman::p_load()` default behaviour being not to update packages that already exist in your r library.

Thus, if in this example, you are trying to install `caret` (which you don't have in your library) and it has a dependency `Rcpp` (which is already in your library because it is also a dependency for several other packages that you have already installed, or you installed it separately previously), `pacman::p_load()` will install `caret` and not update `Rcpp`.

This may then generate a conflict if the latest version of `caret` also depends on the latest version of `Rcpp`, but you have an old version of `Rcpp`.

Instead, you can change the `update` argument to `TRUE`:

```
# Check for, install (if necessary) and load packages:
pacman::p_load(dplyr, caret, plyr, update = TRUE)
```

This may not be a sufficiently targeted solution, because it will update the desired packages AND their dependencies, whereas ideally it would be better if only dependencies that failed to meet the minimum required version number for the desired packages are updated.